# Difficulty in using Patterns and Matchers in a single invocation

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, pattern

Salesforce example:

```
Boolean Test = Pattern.matches('a*b', 'aaaaab');
```

I'm attempting to use regular expression on a condition to check if a string has `"You Order # 1234: "`, but it's always returning false. What's wrong with it?

```
String OrderInfo = 'Hello: Purchased: Your Order # 1234: Processed.';
Boolean Test = Pattern.matches('Your Order # \\d{4}: ', OrderInfo);
System.debug(' Test : ' +Test);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up match() which returns true if the entire input string matches the regex, and find() which returns true if the input string contains the regex. The following code returns true for both cases:

```
String OrderInfo = 'Hello: Purchased: Your Order # 1234: Processed.';
Boolean Test = Pattern.matches('.* Your Order # \\d{4}: .*', OrderInfo);
System.debug(' Test : ' +Test);
Boolean Test2 = Pattern.compile('Your Order # \\d{4}:').matcher(OrderInfo).find();
System.debug(' Test2 : ' +Test2);
```